# QT 5.1.1 android packaging error

Tags: android, qt, ant, android-ndk

when i build and deploy app to emulator with sdk targeT 18 or 17 it  works fine but when i set sdk target to 10 i am getting packaging  error...like below

:-1: error: Packaging Error: Command 'C:/ANDROID/apache/bin/ant.bat clean debug' failed.Exit code: 1

i have latest sdk,ndk,ant files ..

and i have re-installed API-level 10 using sdk manager,but also not working..

and i have tried x86 and arm kits also ....

please help me to solve this problem,Google search is not giving any solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ant anymore, switch to gradle. Ant's status on Android is "gonna die soon", everyone left that boat already.